# класс не видит переменную

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, доступ

я не сильно разбираюсь в классах, можете мне объяснить, почему в  классе потомке ColoredPoint нельзя обратиться к переменной x напрямую (переменная x из класса point) и что нужно добавить в код, чтобы получить такую возможность ?
Ошибка на 75-80 строчках

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Point
{
private:
    int x, y;// создаем координаты точки

public:

    Point()// конструктор без параметров
    {
        std::cout << "Point()\n";
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }
    Point(int x, int y)//конструктор с параметрами(для инициализации значений)
    {
        cout << "Point(int x,int y)\n";
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;

    }
    Point(const Point& p)// конструктор с параметром-объектом того же класса
    {
        cout << "Point(const Point&p)\n";
        x = p.x;
        y = p.y;

    }
    ~Point()
    {
        cout << x << " " << y << endl;
        cout << "~Point()\n";
    }
    void ChangeCoords(int addCoordX, int addCoordY)// метод для линии
    {
        cout << "void ChangeCoords(int addCoordX,int addCoordY)" << endl;
        x += addCoordX;
        y += addCoordY;

    }
    void resetCoords();//метод с реализацией вне класса
    
};
void Point::resetCoords()
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}

class ColoredPoint : public Point
{
protected:
    int color;// создаем координаты точки

public:

    ColoredPoint() : Point()// конструктор без параметров
    {
        cout << "ColoredPoint()\n";
        color = 0;
    }
    ColoredPoint(int x, int y, int color) :Point(x, y)//конструктор с параметрами(для инициализации значений)
    {
        cout << "ColoredPoint(int x, int y)\n";
        this->color = color;
    }
    ColoredPoint(const ColoredPoint& p)// конструктор с параметром-объектом того же класса
    {
        cout << "ColoredPoint(const Point& p)\n";
        color = p.color;
        x = p.x;
        y = p.y;

    }
    ~ColoredPoint()
    {
        cout << x << " " << y << " " << color << endl;
        //printf("%d, %d color=%d\n", x, y, color);
        cout << "~ColoredPoint()\n";
    }
    void ChangeCoords(int new_color)// метод для линии
    {
        cout << "void ChangeCoords(int addCoordX,int addCoordY)" << endl;
        color = new_color;

    }
};

int main()
{

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int choice;

    for (;;)
    {
        cout << "Проверить создание\n";
        cout << "0. Статически созданных объектов" << endl;
        cout << "1. Динамически созданных объектов" << endl;
        cout << "2. Проверить метод ChangeCoords и resetCoords" << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 0:
        {
            //создание статических объектов
            Point p;//создание объекта класса при помощи конструктора без параметров
            Point p2(15, 20);// создание объекта класса при помощи конструктора с параметрами
            Point p3(p2);//создание объекта класса при помощи конструктора копирования
        }
        case 1:
        {
            // создание динамических объектов
            Point* p4 = new Point;//создание объекта класса при помощи конструктора без параметров
            Point* p5 = new Point(20, 30);//создание объекта класса при помощи конструктора с параметрами
            Point* p6 = new Point(*p5);//создание объекта класса при помощи конструктора копирования
            //передача разыменованного указателя на другой объект

            //освобождение памяти динамически созданных экземпляров класса
            delete p4;
            delete p5;
            delete p6;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            Point* p = new Point(4, 6);
            p->resetCoords();
            p->ChangeCoords(-2, 4);
            
            delete p;
        }
        case 3:
        {

        }

        }
    }





    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В примере отсутствуют дружественные классы. Поле x в `Point` объявлено как `private`, соответственно и доступно только из методов этого же класса. Делайте геттер.

Comment: извините , не дружественный класс , а потомок

Answer (score 5):

Если вы хотите обращаться к членам предка — они должны быть объявлены как `protected`:

```
protected:
    int x, y;// создаем координаты точки
```

При этом извне обратиться к этим членам никто все равно не сможет.

Нет никакой необходимости делать наследника другом (впрочем, вы это и не делаете).

Конечно, можно было бы объявить его таковым —

```
class Point
{
    friend class ColoredPoint;
private:
    int x, y;// создаем координаты точки
```

но смысла это не имеет.

Comment: Хотелось бы ознакомиться с резонами минусующего анони... ма. Что не так? Дайте свой **верный** ответ, поясните мне мою ошибку...

Comment: я случайно нажал